# Is a literal an RDF resource?

Tags: rdf, rdfs

Like a lot of people, I use `rdf:Statement`s to reify triples so that I can make statements about statements, like

```
:S1 a rdf:Statement .
:S1 :citation :tabloid_celebrity1 .
:S1 rdf:subject :Earth . 
:S1 rdf:predicate :has_shape . 
:S1 rdf:object :flat_surface .
```

One of my favorite websites, https://www.infowebml.ws/rdf-owl/, says that [the `rdfs:range` of `rdf:object` is `rdfs:Resource`.](https://www.infowebml.ws/rdf-owl/object.htm)

Are literals considered `rdfs:Resource`s?  If not, does that mean that property `rdf:object` shouldn't take a literal as its object?  I.e., is this illegal?

```
:S2 a rdf:Statement .
:S2 :citation <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_the_Earth> .
:S2 rdf:subject :Earth . 
:S2 rdf:predicate :has_age_years . 
:S2 rdf:object "4.54E9"^^xsd:double .
```

Comment: @MarkMiller, cf. [5.3.4](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_object) and also 2.1 and 2.3.

Comment: Your final example is very similar to another example from the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-primer/#reification), therefore hardly illegal.

Comment: It might be confusing but the important thing to know is the semantics of RDF/RDFS, in which RDF literals are a subset of all RDF resources, more formally *the set `IL` of typed literals is mapped into the set of resources `IR`* when doing simple entailment. The key difference here is that we have to distinguish between the RDF literals and the literal values. Probably uninteresting for everybody here, I know :D Long story short, your reification is legal RDF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `rdfs:Literal`s are `rdfs:Resource`s. Everything is an `rdfs:Resource`. You are an `rdfs:Resource`, section 5.3.4 of RDF Schema 1.1 is an `rdfs:Resource`, the number of atoms in planet Earth is an `rdfs:Resource`, complex numbers are `rdfs:Resource`s, `rdfs:Resource` is an `rdfs:Resource`, and an `xsd:double` like `"4.54E9"^^xsd:double` is an `rdfs:Resource`. More precisely `rdfs:Resource` is the IRI of the `rdfs:Class` that has *everything* as its instances.

Or, even more formally, everything in the universe is related to what `rdfs:Resource` denotes in the extension (IEXT) of the resource denoted by `rdf:type`.