# Is an rdfs:Literal "x" an rdfs:Resource of rdf:value "x"?

Tags: rdf, rdfs

The W3C Recommendation *[RDF 1.1 Semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/)* [states](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#patterns-of-rdf-entailment-informative) that if an RDF graph S contains

```
ex:xxx ex:aaa "sss"^^ex:ddd .
```

for ex:ddd in D, then S entails, recognizing D,

```
ex:xxx ex:aaa _:nnn .
_:nnn rdf:type ex:ddd .
```

Given RDFS entailment patterns.

Can we also say that it entails

```
ex:xxx ex:aaa _:nnn .
_:nnn rdf:value "sss" ;
rdf:type ex:ddd .
```

?

**[Edit to reflect on the comment.]**
If not, why? How could `"sss"^^ex:ddd` imply `_:a rdf:type ex:ddd .` and not `_:a rdf:value "sss"; rdf:type ex:ddd .`? Does it really need to be an entailment pattern? Isn't it enough that `rdf:value` denotes the value of the resource? Isn't it implied that if `"sss"^^ex:ddd` allows us to say "Oh, there's a resource of type ex:ddd!" then we can also state its value?
**[End of edit]**

And if it is, does this

```
ex:a ex:p [ rdf:value "1" ; rdf:type xsd:integer ] .
```

Entails this

```
ex:a ex:p "1"^^xsd:integer .
```

?

I cannot find any rule backing this up, but it makes intuitive sense to me that somehow `"sss"^^ex:ddd` is logically equivalent to `_:a rdf:value "sss"; rdf:type ex:ddd .`

I think my question is equivalent to this one: is an rdfs:Literal "x" a rdfs:Resource of rdf:value "x"?

Comment: no, the set of rules in https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/ is complete, there is no such rule that does infer `rdf:value` triples nor is there any equivalence rule

Comment: I didn't find any explicit that does infer this either. But in what way this set of rules is "complete"? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

This is the most definite answer I was able to come up with:

1. The [Formal Model for RDF](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-rdf-syntax-19990222/#model) states that "1. There is a set called *Resources*." and "2. There is a set called *Literals*." but states nothing regarding the relationship between those two sets. In particular *Literals* could well be a subset a *Resources*.
2. The [Formal Model for RDF](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-rdf-syntax-19990222/#model) states that "4. There is a set called *Statements*, each element of which is a triple of the form `{pred, sub, obj}` Where pred is a property (member of *Properties*), sub is a resource (member of *Resources*), and obj is either a resource or a literal (member of *Literals*)."
3. The [RDF Schema 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_resource) states that "All things described by RDF are called resources, and are instances of the class `rdfs:Resource`". Therefore the set called *Resources* in the formal model and `rdfs:Resource` are the same thing.
4. The [RDF Schema 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_object) states that `rdf:object` "is used to state the object of a statement" and that its range is `rdfs:Resource`.
5. It was stated in the second point that every `rdf:object` of an `rdf:Statement` may be an RDF *Literal*. Therefore the fourth point above implies that the set of RDF *Literals* is indeed a subset of RDF *Resources*, that is by the third point: `rdfs:Resource`. (And this is consistent with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48195644/8158930).)
6. Consistently with everything stated above, the [RDF Schema 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_value) states that the range of `rdf:value` is also `rdfs:Resource`.
7. As mentioned in OP, the [RDF 1.1 Semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#patterns-of-rdf-entailment-informative) states that "if S contains `xxx aaa "sss"^^ddd .` for ddd in D then S RDF entails, recognizing D, `xxx aaa _:nnn . _:nnn rdf:type ddd .`" Which means: "if the `rdfs:Resource` xxx is linked to the RDF *Literal* "sss"^^ex:ddd, then we can say that xxx is linked to an `rdfs:Resource` the `rdf:type` of which is ex:ddd". This makes sense to say that there is an `rdfs:Resource` of this `rdf:type` because we known now as a fact that "sss"^^ddd (a RDF *Literal*) is indeed an `rdfs:Resource`.
8. The [RDF Schema 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_value) states that "`rdf:value` [...] may be used in describing structured values", which is **exactly** what we do when we apply this entailment regime.

Therefore, while it is written nowhere explicitly that `"sss"^^ex:ddd` is logically equivalent to `_:a rdf:value "sss"^^ex:ddd; rdf:type ex:ddd .`, I think that we can confidently say that it is. This is entirely consistent with every source I cited. RDF Schema 1.1 states that "`rdf:value` has no meaning on its own" and is "provided as a piece of vocabulary that may be used in idioms such as illustrated". In other words, it's only another way of saying the same thing.

My conclusion is that we can say `"sss"^^ex:ddd` implies `_:a rdf:value "sss"^^ex:ddd; rdf:type ex:ddd .` and conversely `_:a` is precisely `"sss"^^ex:ddd`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an even more definite answer I was able to come up with. It clarifies some misconceptions I had when I came up with the previous answer.

1. [RDF 1.1 Concepts and Abstract Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#resources-and-statements) states that "Any IRI or literal denotes something in the world (the 'universe of discourse'). These things are called **resources**."
2. [RDF 1.1 Concepts and Abstract Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-Graph-Literal) states that "A literal in an RDF graph consists of two or three elements: a **lexical form** (...), a **datatype IRI** (...), a non-empty **language tag** (...)".
3. [RDF 1.1 Concepts and Abstract Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#referents) states: "The resource denoted by an IRI is also called its **referent**."
4. [It](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-Graph-Literal) similarly states about Literals the difference between the literal and its value.
5. It also states: "Unlike IRIs and literals, blank nodes do not identify specific resources. Statements involving blank nodes say that something with the given relationships exists, without explicitly naming it." More precisely, [RDF 1.1 Semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#blank-nodes) states that "Blank nodes are treated as simply indicating the existence of a thing, without using an IRI to identify any particular thing."
6. [RDF 1.1 Concepts and Abstract Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-blank-nodes) also states that **Blank Nodes** are disjoint from IRIs and Literals.

In other words: a resource can be named (with an IRI), can be shown (with a literal representing it), or its existence can be stated without naming it nor showing it (thanks to blank nodes).

In standard RDF, Statements' subjects can only be IRIs or Blank Nodes. Therefore the only possible way to to talk about a resource that is not named (no IRI) is to use a blank node (existential variable). RDF gives us an idiomatic construction to do so: `_:nnn rdf:value "sss"` (see [RDF Schema 1.1 section 5.4.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_value)). This reads: "there exists a resource, the value of which is the value denoted by 'sss'."

Therefore, `ex:xxx ex:aaa "sss"^^ex:ddd .` can be rewritten `ex:xxx ex:aaa _:nnn . _:nnn rdf:value "sss"^^ex:ddd .` without needing any entailment pattern, because it is not so much a logical conclusion than a grammatical equivalence. (For such a simple case it is obviously of no use and more confusing than clarifying.)

Therefore it makes sense that `ex:xxx ex:aaa "sss"^^ex:ddd .` entails `ex:xxx ex:aaa _:nnn . _:nnn rdf:type ex:ddd .`, because here it is the same `_:nnn` as before. If it wasn't the case, the entailement would only be `_:nnn rdf:type ex:ddd .` and not `ex:xxx ex:aaa _:nnn . _:nnn rdf:type ex:ddd .`.

In [generalized RDF](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#bib-HORST04) we can use a literal as a subject. Aptly, it defines a generalized entailment pattern stating that `ex:xxx ex:aaa "sss"^^ex:ddd .` entails `"sss"^^ex:ddd rdf:type ex:ddd .`, which is consistent with the explanation given.

But the confusing thing is the difference between the resource and the "handle" we use to talk about it (IRI versus its referent, literal (2 or 3 components) versus literal value, existential variable). One could argue that the thing the type of which is `ex:ddd` is the literal, and not the literal value itself. (See [RDF 1.1 Concepts and Abstract Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-Graph-Literal) for the difference between the literal and its value.) But then again, if `_:nnn` stated the existence of the literal in this exemple, it wouldn't be the object of the triple `ex:xxx ex:aaa _:nnn .`. (Note: if we want to talk about the lexical form itself (which is a thing we may want to talk about, and therefore is a resource), we have no other choice than using a blank node (existential value), *even in generalized RDF* or giving it an IRI. Plus: the datatype is not the `rdf:type` of the lexical form, but only a component of the literal (composed of the lexical form and the datatype and maybe a language tag).)

Thankfully, [RDF 1.1 Semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#rdfs-interpretations) states: "the semantic conditions on RDF interpretations, together with the RDFS conditions on ICEXT, mean that every recognized datatype can be treated as a class whose extension is the value space of the datatype, and every literal with that datatype either fails to refer, or refers to a value in that class." In other words, while it is true to say that `ex:ddd` is the datatype of the literal `"sss"^^ex:ddd`, it is also true to say that `ex:ddd` is the class of the literal value denoted by `"sss"^^ex:ddd`.

So to answer the OP:

1. `ex:xxx ex:aaa "sss"^^ex:ddd .` and `ex:xxx ex:aaa [ rdf:value "sss"^^ex:ddd ; rdf:type ex:ddd ] .` are equivalent by a mix of entailment pattern and grammatical equivalence. (Beware of the datatype "`^^ex:ddd`" that has been ommitted in the OP.)
2. `ex:a ex:p [ rdf:value "1" ; rdf:type xsd:integer ] .` doesn't entail `ex:a ex:p "1"^^xsd:integer .` but `ex:a ex:p [ rdf:value "1"^^xsd:integer ; rdf:type xsd:integer ] .` should (the datatype was ommitted).